# how do I delay and get after a return with celery and django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

Currently trying to clean how `celery` works with django which was told can work asynchronous

I have run the simple `celery` task which works fine following the documentation so I do believe I have celery installed and running fine.

But somehow I am not sure how it can work and run after a `return`

for example

I have this as to create a new user task

```
@app.task
def new_user(first, last, table):
    user = UserProfile()
    user.first_name = first
    user.last_name = last
    user.table = table
    user.save()
    return user
```

I have a post api call just to make it as a sample on how celery works.

I have this in my view

```
class List(View):
    def post(self, request):
        all_users = UserMQS().profile()
        output = []
        for user in all_users:
            output.append({
                'id': user.id,
                'first_name': user.first_name,
                'last_name': user.last_name
            })

        ns = new_user.s('First Name1', 'Last Name1', "Table1")
        res = ns.delay()
        return JsonResponse(output, safe=False)
        res.get()
```

I also tried something like `new_user.delay('First Name1', 'Last Name1', "Table1")` but doesn't work though.

Can someone give me an idea how this can be done?

I want the `return JsonResponse` to be running WHILE `new_user` is created.  This isn't just for creating `new_user` I am just doing it to test how celery works so I can implement some other things once I get a hold of celery.

Thanks in advance for any advises.

Comment: If you want to get an error fixed, you might want to show one? :) What does your celery worker tells in the logs? How does your celery configuration looks like?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible - at least not with this approach. A method can not do something after it has returned. You need to decide whether you want to wait for the result of the task or directly return something to the client.

If you want a quick response for the user (directly return) you need another communication channel between the browser and your django/task queue

One solution might be the [django result backend](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_celery_results) which writes results from your tasks in the django database. Together with that you can create another view which you call from the browser until the result is present aka [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/).

Or you have a look on [websockets](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). They enable you to send something from the server to the client without the browser asking in front. In the django world there is [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which you might want to look at. Channels might be a replacement for celery in this case.

This were just a few possible ways to achieve what you described.

Comment: I guess I got the wrong idea of using celery, I do not really need to call `res.get()` after `return` what I really want is, having the `return` do it's job while `new_user` is being created, this is just a simplified version of what I want, there will be lots going on with the `new_user` function which will not affect the result on the `return`  But it would take awhile if waiting for `new_user` to be done then show the `return` (if using celery, what am I missing to get this to work though?)

Comment: also, thanks for bring up channel, when I googled, celery popped up instead of channel.  Nice to know another new thing (more to learn)